# Distribuir programa JavaFX con imágenes desde eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Saludos, estoy desarrollando un pequeño programa en el ide Eclipse usando javaFx, y la cosa es que añado icono para la stage o imagenes desde el scene builder y cuando ejecuto desde eclipse todo perfecto, pero cuando le doy a exportar... y elijo jar ejecutable se abre la APP pero ni el icono ni las imágenes aparecen, estas se encuentran en una carpeta en el proyecto llamada /images.

Me gustaría saber la manera correcta de exportar el programa sin instalador, mi idea es hacerlo portable en un carpeta que contenga las imagenes necesarias, archivos de configuración etc...

Leyendo en San Google pone que basta con copiar en la misma carpeta que el ejecuble la carpeta que contenga los recursos esto ultimo no me ha funcionado.

Gracias a cualquier ayuda!

---

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:images/playlist.png")); 

    initRootLayout();

    showPersonOverview();
}
```

Esto en el metodo start(), pero luego otras imagenes las añado en el Scene Builder y lo mismo da.
En cuanto a la ejecución lo hago desde Linux, con la orden;

```
java -jar fichero.jar
```

Comment: Y no te tira ningún error al ejecutar por fuera de eclipse?

Comment: No todo va bien, solo que no muestra ninguna de las imágenes, ni iconos

Comment: Me intriga como ejecutas el jar. Lo haces desde la terminal ?? De manera que si te tira algún error te lo muestre. Ayer justamente tenia el problema que me dices tu y netbeans compilaba bien pero cuando ejecutaba el jar no . Parece que el paquete que contenia las imágenes se compilaba con un nombre anterior y por eso no me detectaba las imágenes. Intenta ejecutar desde CMD o  la terminal con la opción `java -jar tuPrograma.jar` en windows. En linux no recuerdo.

Comment: Y por cierto, como agregas las imágenes? Son con el editor o dinámicamente? Debí haber preguntado eso en un principio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal cual lo tienes, veo que metes mal la ruta.
Si mantienes una carpeta al mismo nivel donde está el proyecto y escribes esta línea de la forma:

```
primaryState.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/playlist.png"));
```

No deberías tener problemas al leer la ruta.

Un saludo.